# How to turn Java class into one of its subclasses (SocketAddress and InetSocketAddress)

Tags: java, class, sockets, networking, inetaddress

I am trying to get the IP of a socket connection in string form.

I am using a framework, which returns the `SocketAddress` of the received message. How can i transform it to `InetSocketAddress` or `InetAddress`?

Comment: welcome to SO. The answer that has been most useful and eventually solved your problem should be marked as accepted. This is done using the tick below the vote counter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your certain that the object is an `InetSocketAddress` then simply cast it:

```
SocketAddress sockAddr = ...
InetSocketAddress inetAddr = (InetSocketAddress)sockAddr;
```

You can then call the `getAddress()` method on `inetAddr` to get the `InetAddress` object associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, I am much more of a php dev and new to Java, so the whole casting process is new to me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You can try casting to it. In this case this is [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java).

```
InetSocketAddress isa = (InetSocketAddress) socketAddress;
```

However, this may throw `ClassCastException` if the class isn't really what you expect.

Checks can be made on this via the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (socketAddress instanceof InetSocketAddress) {
    InetSocketAddress isa = (InetSocketAddress) socketAddress;
    // invoke methods on "isa". This is now safe - no risk of exceptions
}
```

The same check can be done for other subclasses of `SocketAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `SocketAddress` is an abstract class, so you receive some subclass of it. Did you try to cast returned `SocketAddress` to `InetSocketAddress`?