# Java Serializable (are all variables affected?)

Tags: java, parsing, serialization, object

I want to kow whether the attribute `foo` will also be serialized in the following example or not (written out of my mind):

```
public class Example implements Serializable {
     private String a = "a";
     private Foo foo = new Foo("a");
}
```

NOTE: Class Foo only holds an attribute `a` and does **not** implement Serializable

If `Foo` is not Serializable, I have the other problem, that Foo cannot implement `Serializable`, because it is provided by an Api Call from an external `.jar`-file.
Also in my concrete case Foo holds also an class `Bar` which is also not `Serializable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Foo` is not Serializable, an attempt to serialize an instance of Example with a non-null `foo` will result in a `NotSerializableException`, unless `foo` is declared `transient`.

You could have found that out sourself quite easily by simply trying it out.

**Update:**
In order to be able to serialize instances of `Example` when you cannot change `Foo` but need to preserve its contents, you can implement the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods as described in the [API doc of `Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 2):

If the `foo` instance is not `Serializable`, the serialisation of `Example` will fail at runtime - try it!

You can provide a custom serialised form of `Example` by providing `readObject` and `writeObject` methods.

Comment: thank you. Anyways... now I have an other problem - `Foo` cannot implement Serializable, because that class is Provided by an Api call from an external `.jar`. Something like subclassing `Foo` into something like `SerializableFoo` (which implements `Selializable`) will neither work, because I cannot cast from super to subclass (regarding to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass)

Comment: @gluca You need to work out how you would transform a `Foo` into a sequence of bytes (or serialisable objects) and back, then put that in (or call it from) the `Example` `readObject` and `writeObject`.

Answer (score 2):

If `Foo` is not serializable, trying to serialize an `Example` instance will throw a runtime exception. You need to make it serializable, or mark the foo field as `transient`. But in the latter case, when deserializing the example, foo will be null.

Answer (score 1):

See [NotSerializableException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html).

Only `transient` fields are not omitted during serialization.

Comment: @Michael Typo :) Took care of it in Ninja Edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Then **no**.

You'll get this:

```
   java.io.NotSerializableException: Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to deal with custom serialization if you want to get your Example object to be serialized. here you go:
1. Given the Foo comes from the jar you can't change, make it transient (otherwise you'll get an exception in runtime, as was stated before). 
2. Define "readObject"/"writeObject" and from there manage your serialization process. 
 - Call the defaultWriteObject to make Java serializing what it can serialize.
extract the state of the foo class (in your example, the internal state of Foo is "a") 
 - serialize explicitly the "a"
The same should be done during the deserialization:
 - invoke the default deserialization mechanism
 - deserialize "a" (you know that right after the default data there is your custom String in the stream)
 - create the Foo instance from A from the readObject.

In general I would recommend to read about this in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" book - he has a nice coverage of this topic there.
In addition there are a lot of examples in internet

For example [Serialization Example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45)

Hope this helps

Mark