# Classes Hierarchy and Casting between Objects

Tags: java, casting

as far as i know **it's not possible to cast an Object of a superclass into an Object of a subclass**. This will compile but during runtime it will return an error.

More specifically, given the following Hierarchy of Classes and Interfaces:

. Alpha is a superclass for Beta and Gamma
. Gamma is a superclass for Delta and Omega
. Interface "In" is implemented by Beta and Delta

In this scenario i define the following code:

```
Delta r;
Gamma q;
```

Is this correct?

```
r = (Delta) q;
```

Can i cast q to type Delta even if Delta is a subclass of Gamma?
I think this isn't possible, my text book says otherwise. I already searched a lot and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass) i'm right and this is an error from the textbook.

**Am i missing anything?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is legal:

```
Gamma q = new Delta();
Delta d = (Delta)q;
```

This will compile but will give you a runtime error:

```
Gamma q = new Gamma();
Delta d = (Delta)q;
```

In the first case, `q` is a `Delta`, so you can cast it to a `Delta`.  In the second case, `q` is a `Gamma`, so you cannot case it to a `Delta.`

A `Gamma` *variable* can refer to a `Gamma` *object* or to an object that is a subclass of `Gamma`, e.g. a `Delta` object; when you cast a `Gamma` to a `Delta` then you are telling the compiler that the `Gamma` variable refers to a `Delta` object or to an object that is a subclass of `Delta` (and if you're wrong then you'll get a `ClassCastException`).  The types of the objects themselves are immutable - you cannot change the type of a `Gamma` object to a `Delta` object at runtime, so if a `Gamma` variable actually refers to a `Gamma` object but you then try to cast it to a `Delta` object then you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: I had the same idea but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: FYI: the book refers to the second case mentioned in the answer.

Thank you!