# Can't convert from Abstract<Generic> to Concrete:Abstract<Concrete:Generic>

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMessageProcessor<T> where T: BaseMessage {
        void Process(T msg);
    }
```

I have an abstract class that implements this interface:

```
 public abstract class AMessageProcessor<T> : IMessageProcessor<T> where T : BaseMessage {

        protected Controller Controller { get; private set; }

        public AMessageProcessor(Controller controller) {
            Controller = controller;
        }

        public abstract void Process(T msg);
    }
```

then I have a message:

```
 public class RRMessage : BaseMessage {
  ...
 }
```

and then I have an implementation:

```
public class RRMessageProcessor : AMessageProcessor<RRMessage> {
      public RRMessageProcessor(Controller controller) : base(controller) {}

      public override void Process(RRMessage msg) {

            //do something here
        }
    }
```

Now in another class I would like to make a list of these processors for different messages:

```
 public readonly List<AMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>> AvailableMessageProcessors;

        public MessageProcessingStrategy(Controller controller) {
            AvailableMessageProcessors = new List<AMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>>();

            /* ----- ERROR HAPPENS AT THIS LINE ------ */
            AvailableMessageProcessors.Add(new RRMessageProcessor(controller));

        }
```

And I get this error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'RRMessageProcessor' to
>   'AMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>'

Seems like that conversion should work... Why can't it convert? How can I get it to work?

Comment: There's no safe way to do this. If it were allowed you could pass a `BaseMessage` to `RRMessage.Process` which requires an `RRMessage` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem in my other answer (deleted) about covariant types in parameters but an approach like this may solves your problem:

1. Defines a `BaseMessageProcessor` class (could be `AMessageProcessor`) like this one:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseMessageProcessor
   {
       protected Controller Controller { get; private set; }

       public BaseMessageProcessor(Controller controller)
       {
           Controller = controller;
       }

       public void Process<T>(T msg) where T : BaseMessage
       {
           if (this is IMessageProcessor<T>)
               (this as IMessageProcessor<T>).Process(msg);

           throw new NotSupportedException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Defines an interface `IMessageProcessorOf<T>`:

   ```
   public interface IMessageProcessor<T> where T : BaseMessage
   {
       void Process(T msg);
   }
   ```
3. Defines concrete processors inheriting of `BaseMessageProcessor` and implementing (explicitly) `IMessageProcessorOf<T>`:

   ```
   public class RRMessageProcessor : BaseMessageProcessor, IMessageProcessorOf<RRMessage>
   {
       public RRMessageProcessor(Controller controller) : base(controller) { }

       void IMessageProcessor<RRMessage>.Process(RRMessage msg)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

This solution allows you to work with `AvailableMessageProcessors`:

```
public List<BaseMessageProcessor> AvailableMessageProcessors;

...

AvailableMessageProcessors = new List<BaseMessageProcessor>();
AvailableMessageProcessors.Add(new RRMessageProcessor(controller));
```

So, if you have 2 messages types like `RRMessage` and `SSMessage`, you can define one `MultiMessageProcessor`:

```
public class MultiMessageProcessor : BaseMessageProcessor, IMessageProcessorOf<RRMessage>, IMessageProcessorOf<SSMessage>
{
    public MultiMessageProcessor(Controller controller) : base(controller) { }

    void IMessageProcessorOf<RRMessage>.Process(RRMessage msg)
    {
        ...
    }

    void IMessageProcessorOf<SSMessage>.Process(SSMessage msg)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The calls to `Process()` method will be made through `BaseMessageProcessor.Process<>`:

```
multiProcessor.Process(new RRMessage());
multiProcessor.Process(new SSMessage());
```

Or just use `RRMessageProcessor` and define a `SSMessageProcessor` using the same idea like before.

Comment: awesome! This works great! and I like the flexibility of being able to process multiple messages in the same MessageProcessor!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest/prettiest way to do it but it seems to work. Here's what I changed in **AMessageProcessor**:

```
public abstract class AMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>

        protected Controller Controller { get; private set; }

        public AMessageProcessor(Controller controller) {
            Controller = controller;
        }

        /* ----- REALLY DON'T WANT TO OVERRIDE THIS METHOD EVERYWHERE --- */
        public abstract void Process(BaseMessage msg);
    }
```

And then changing the **RRMessageProcessor** as:

```
public class RRMessageProcessor : AMessageProcessor, IMessageProcessor<RRMessage> {
      public RRMessageProcessor(Controller controller) : base(controller) {}

      /* ----- REALLY DON'T WANT TO OVERRIDE THIS METHOD LIKE THIS EVERYWHERE --- */
      public override void Process(BaseMessage msg) {
            Process(msg as RRMessage);
        }

      public void Process(RRMessage msg) {

            //do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can avoid this by creating a wrapper class `ProcWrapper<T> : IMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>` which contains an `IMessageProcessor<T>` and does the cast in its `Process` method. This is the best you can do since this approach is unsafe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On your generic type you'll need to define the type as covariant. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx

This should work

```
public interface IMessageProcessor<in T> where T : BaseMessage
{
    void Process(T msg);
}
```

Comment: am getting the same error. Can you show the full code? (not just this change)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily solve your problem by redefining

`public readonly List<AMessageProcessor<BaseMessage>> AvailableMessageProcessors;`

into

`public readonly List<RRMessageProcessor> AvailableMessageProcessors;`

So you don't have cast problems and you're using the you're custom objects

hope to help!

Comment: But my list will contain different message processors, not just RRMessageProcessor - that is just one of the processors. My list will have other message processors that will inherit from AMessageProcessor

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506587/classes-hierarchy-and-casting-between-objects