# ArrayList cannot be cast to custom class extending ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, serializable

I have class mentioned below:

```
public class JsonHistoryList extends ArrayList<JsonHistory> implements Serializable{}
```

I wish to pass it through intent using

```
timerService.putExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG, activities);
```

But after I receive it (way below)

```
JsonHistoryList temp = (JsonHistoryList) intent.getSerializableExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG);
```

in my service it gives me exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.epstim.captime.jsonmodel.JsonHistoryList
```

I don't understand why java can't handle that operation.

I've changed my code in service to:

```
ArrayList<JsonHistory> temp = (ArrayList<JsonHistory>) intent.getSerializableExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG);
activities.addAll(temp);
```

And it worked.

Comment: try cleaning your project and running it again.

Comment: what is activities? are you sure is `JsonHistoryList` ?

Comment: Please print `temp.getClass().toString()` and tell us what it is.

Comment: activities is a list of JsonHistoryList ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the internals, android puts every extra in  a special Map and doesn't record how exactly you want it parcelled.

At some point android will flattern your extras into parcel, and it will do so by checking each object type (since, as I said, it doesn't remember how you want it).

Parcel supports both writeList and writeSerializable and your JsonHistoryList is also both (list of serializables and a serialisable itself)

So android parcelling goes like this:

```
for (Object object : extras) {
   //... check for other types here
   } else if (object instanceof List) {
     parcel.writeList(object); // This what happens in your case and will be unparcelled into arraylist
   } else if (object instanceof Serializable) {
     parcel.writeSerializable(object); // What you really want, but percelling never will get here
   }
}
```

If you want to preserve list you need to create a class that will be serializable and won't extend arraylist but will contain it inside.

```
public class SuperJsonHistory implements Serializable {
  private JsonHistoryList yourList;
  ...
}
```

So composition over inheritance in case you want to preserve type

Comment: Do you know if Parcelable is above List in this type checking list? I would prefer to have my class inherit ArrayList, if I can!

Comment: This just saved me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens if `intent.getSerializableExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG);` returns an object of class `ArrayList<JsonHistory>` and not an object of type `JSONHistoryList`.

We cannot forcefully downcast a parent object.

Consider your example,say

public class JsonHistoryList extends ArrayList implements Serializable{
   public int someField ;// can by anything
}

For simplicity, if your `getSerializableExtra();` returns, `new ArrayList<JsonHistory>()`, when you try to downcast this to `JsonHistoryList`, it cannot cast so because `someField` values cannot be determinied

Comment: But why intent.getSerializableExtra(); returns ArrayList not JsonHistoryList?

Comment: I think your `activities` is of type `ArrayList<JsonHistory>` and thats why it is returning an `ArrayList`

Comment: in both files: private JsonHistoryList activities; first is Activity and second Service

Answer (score 0):

we cannot cast a superclass object into a sub-class object.

Cast is only possible if object which is to be casted passes the IS-A relationship.

you can have a look at this link.It will clear all doubts
[explicit casting from super class to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

So if `JsonHistoryList extends ArrayList`, then a `JsonHistoryList` is an `ArrayList` but an `ArrayList` is not necessarily a `JsonHistoryList`. You expected your own subclass, but that's not what you got back.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, I just add a wrapper class which implements Serializable:

```java
public class JsonHistoryListWrapper implement Serializable {
    JsonHistoryList jsonHistoryList;

    private JsonHistoryListWrapper(JsonHistoryList jsonHistoryList) {
        this.jsonHistoryList = jsonHistoryList;
    }

    public static JsonHistoryListWrapper wrapper(JsonHistoryList jsonHistoryList) {
        return new JsonHistoryListWrapper(jsonHistoryList);
    }
}
```