# Strange ClassCastException when calling Intent.getSerializableExtra()

Tags: android

I have the following class:

```
public class IdList extends ArrayList<Long> {

    public IdList() {
        super();
    }

    public IdList(Collection<Long> idCollection) {
        super(idCollection);
    }
}
```

I pass an instance of this class to an `IntentService` with the following code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra(MyService.IDS, ids);
startService(intent);
```

And i use the following code to fetch it in the `Service`:

```
IdList ids = (IdList) intent.getSerializableExtra(IDS);
```

Which results in the following `ClassCastException`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   my.package.IdList

**BUT**

Sending an object of the same type (`IdList`) from the `Service` by using `LocalBroadcastManager` and fetching it in `onReceive()` (via the same method, by calling `getSerializableExtra()` on the `Intent` and casting to `IdList`) **works flawlessly**.

No `ClassCastException` thrown.

Why is this happening? Is this a bug in Android?

*EDIT:*

I'm using the following method to instantiate my `IdList` object:

```
public IdList getIds() {
    return selectedIds.isEmpty() ? null : new IdList(selectedIds);
}
```

`selectedIds` is a `HashSet<Long>` object.

*EDIT2:*

**I'm not looking for a workaround**. I'd like to know why the same code works perfectly fine when the `Intent` is sent through a broadcast and why does it throw a `ClassCastException` when it is passed through the `startService()` call.

Comment: How do you instantiate `ids` before the call to `intent.putExtra(MyService.IDS, ids);`?

Comment: Please show your code for instantiating the `ids` variable.

Comment: There's a nice article regarding your problem: [The mysterious case of the Bundle and the Map](https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-mysterious-case-of-the-bundle-and-the-map-7b15279a794e#.l9yencapv) - should work for ArrayLists, too ;-) It explains the problem and suggests a workaround.

Comment: @gus42 Have you read my question? I'm perfectly aware there are several workarounds, but i'm not asking for a workaround. I'm asking why a `ClassCastException` is thrown in the first scenario and why is the same code working without any problems in the second one (when sending the `Intent` as a broadcast).

Comment: Here is the explanation to why it happens http://stackoverflow.com/a/25626637/2267723

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using serializing .. use Parcelable instead of that

Make your IdList class Parcelable, then you can get put/get your object

```
intent.putParcelableArrayList(ids);

IdList ids = (IdList) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(IDS);
```

I hope that may help,'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm aware of the possible workarounds. I'm not looking for a workaround but asking why is the problem described in my question happening.