# Polymorphism with Objectify client side (android/ios)

Tags: android, objective-c, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm using Google Endpoints with Objectify to create my server.
Entity A is superclass of class B and class C; server side I've annotated like shown in [Entity Polymorphism](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Polymorphism).

Then i write APIs for class A, and libraries to import in Android/iOs

Now, the problem is: client side i can retrieve class A, but i cannot access (using cast) to B and C properties

eg:

> ((B) A).getBProp();

obtaining a ClassCastException in java (end equivalent to objective-c).

The strange thing is that on Google Dashboard i can see the correct subclasses (^d and ^i) and also quering from google-apis-explorer i can retrieve all the fields of subclasses.

Is there someone using polymorphism in Objectify capable to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provided, you're casting an instance of class A (superclass) to class B.  [This *will* cause a ClassCastException unless you define a constructor for B that takes an instance of A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253085/4270992).