# ClassCastException using Generics Object[] cannot be cast

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting, classcastexception

So I'm trying to create a class that implements a heap using an array in order to make a prioritized list. In my constructor I want to create an array of Entry objects. Is this possible to do? I have done some generic casting before and I have tried everything that usually works for me. I feel like It should be possible but i can't figure it out.

This is the exception I get when I run it:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Llab09.Entry;

```
`public class ArrayHeap<K,V> implements PriorityQueue<K,V> {
    `private Comparator<K> comp;
     private Entry<K,V>[] data;
     private int heapSize;

     @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
     public ArrayHeap(int size, Comparator<K> c){
        data = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Object[size]; // type casting array
        heapSize = 0;
        comp = c;
    }
 }
```

Also I'll throw in my nested Entry class to look at aswell.

```
protected static class AHEntry<K,V> implements Entry<K,V> {
    private K k;
    private V v;

    public AHEntry(K key, V value){
        k = key;
        v = value;
    }
    public K getKey(){ return k;}
    public V getValue(){ return v;}
    public void setKey(K key){ k = key;}
    public void setValue(V value){ v = value;}
}
```

Comment: I think this applies here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass

Answer (score 1):

The line `data = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Object[size]` is resulting in a type cast error because an `Object` array cannot be cast to a `Map.Entry` array.  The following code makes use of the custom `AHEntry` class which you provided:

```
public class ArrayHeap<K,V> implements PriorityQueue<K,V> {
    private Comparator<K> comp;
    private Entry<K,V>[] data;
    private int heapSize;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public ArrayHeap(int size, Comparator<K> c){
        data = new (AHEntry<K, V>)new AHEntry<?, ?>[size];
        heapSize = 0;
        comp = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the other way around: he's trying to cast an `Object[]` to a `Map.Entry[]`.

Comment: Right, and since this cannot be done we either have to try something else or change the logic of the code.

Comment: Alright thanks that helps me out. I'm going to change it up a bit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I meant this: in your answer you say "... because a `Map.Entry` array cannot be cast to an `Object` array", but it's the other way around: because an `Object` array cannot be cast to a `Map.Entry` array.

Comment: Need to do `new AHEntry[size]` or `(AHEntry<K, V>)new AHEntry<?, ?>[size]`.