# Cast parent class to son calls -java

Tags: java, class, casting, subclass, extends

I have two classes:

```
public class Expression {
  public Expression(){};
    public  void Submeet_In_Expression(double i){};

    public  void Just_Submeet(Double double1){};

    public   double GetValue(){
        return -1;
    };
}
```

and an extends class:

```
public class ExpressionA extends Expression{
    double ans; 
    public ExpressionA(){
        ans=1;
    }
    public void Submeet_In_Expression(double i){
        ans= (ans*(Math.pow(-1,i)/(2*i+1)));
    }
    public void Just_Submeet(Double i) {
        ans*=i; 
    }

    public double GetValue(){
        return ans;
    }

}
```

in one of the functions I'm getting an a ExpressionA (I have ExpressionB, ExpressionC etc) and I what to cast Expression to what ever I will get from the user.

Comment: If I were you, I'd make `Expression` an interface and implement it in different ways. Then you can do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast a super class to a sub class.

> By using a cast you're essentially telling the compiler "trust me. I'm a professional, I know what I'm doing and I know that although you
>   can't guarantee it, I'm telling you that this animal variable is
>   definitely going to be a dog."
>
> Since the animal isn't actually a dog (it's an animal, you could do
>   Animal animal = new Dog(); and it'd be a dog) the VM throws an
>   exception at runtime because you've violated that trust (you told the
>   compiler everything would be ok and it's not!)
>
> The compiler is a bit smarter than just blindly accepting everything,
>   if you try and cast objects in different inheritence hierarchies (cast
>   a Dog to a String for example) then the compiler will throw it back at
>   you because it knows that could never possibly work.
>
> Because you're essentially just stopping the compiler from
>   complaining, every time you cast it's important to check that you
>   won't cause a ClassCastException by using instanceof in an if
>   statement (or something to that effect.)

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass).