# Extend a JDOM Document

Tags: java, jdom-2

For a project at university, I need to parse a GML file. GML files are XML based so I use JDOM2 to parse it. To fit my purposes, I extended org.jdom2.Document like so:

```
package datenbank;

import java.io.File;
// some more imports

public class GMLDatei extends org.jdom2.Document {

    public void saveAsFile() {
        // ...
    }

    public GMLKnoten getRootElement(){
        return (GMLKnoten) this.getDocument().getRootElement();
    }

    public void setRootElement(GMLKnoten root){
        this.getDocument().setRootElement(root);
    }
}
```

I also extended org.jdom2.Element and named the subclass GMLKnoten but this does not matter too much for my question.

When testing, I try to load a GML file. When using the native document and element classes, it loads fine, but when using my subclasses, I get the following scenario:

I load the file using:

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
File inputFile = new File("gml/Roads_Munich_Route_Lines.gml");
GMLDatei document = null;

ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    document = (GMLDatei) saxBuilder.build(inputFile);
} catch (JDOMException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the line

```
document = (GMLDatei) saxBuilder.build(inputFile);
```

I get a Cast-Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jdom2.Document cannot be cast to datenbank.GMLDatei
at datenbank.GMLTest.main(GMLTest.java:27)
```

I thought that casting schould be no problem as I am subclassing org.jdom2.document. What am I missing?

vat

Comment: well it's pretty easy. The `SAXBuilder` returns a `org.jdom2.Document` and not a `GMLDatei`. If you really want to achieve this you'll have to reimplement/extend the `SAXBuilder` in order to create a `GMLDatei` instead of a basic `Document`!

Comment: @ParkerHalo Yeah, I know, but I remember using this method for ages, when e.g. extending a JTable and it worked.

Comment: hm... maybe you created the object by yourself back then (new instance with keyword new) But the problem here is that the SAXParser creates your document instance!

Comment: I instanciate it as null some lines before calling the SAXBuilder

Comment: well I see you're missing some basic knowledge here (no offense). The method `saxBuilder.build(inputFile)` creates a new instance (an object) of `org.jdom2.Document` which is not of type `GMLDatei`. in your line you try to parse the object of type `Document` to `GMLDatei` which is not possible

Comment: If you want some more explanation i can provide an answer to make the problem clear.

Comment: I understand what types are created and recapped the lecuture and now understand too why it throws a CastException. I also found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9253085/5736633

Comment: And thanks for helping @Parker Halo :)

Answer (score 0):

In general I want to "challenge" your requirement to extend Document - what value do you get from your custom classes that are not already part of the native implementation? I ask this for 2 reasons:

- as the maintainer of JDOM, should I be adding some new feature?
- I am just curious.....

JDOM has a system in place for allowing you to extend it's core classes and have a different implementation of them when parsing a document. It is done by extending the `JDOMFactory`.

Consider this code here: [JDOMFactory interface](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/JDOMFactory.java). When `SAXParser` parses a document it uses those methods to build the document.

There is a default, overridable implementation in [DefaultJDOMFactory](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/DefaultJDOMFactory.java) that you can extend, and, for example, in your implementation, you must override the non-final "Element" methods like:

> ```
> @Override
> public Element element(final int line, final int col, final String name,
>       String prefix, String uri) {
>   return new Element(name, prefix, uri);
> }
> ```

and instead have:

```
@Override
public Element element(final int line, final int col, final String name,
        String prefix, String uri) {
    return new GMLKnoten (name, prefix, uri);
}
```

Note that you will have to override all methods that are non-final and return content that is to be customised (for example, you will have to override 4 `Element` methods by my count.

With your own `GMLJDOMFactory` you can then use SAXBuilder by either using the [full constructor `new SAXBuilder(null, null, new GMPJDOMFactory())`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html#SAXBuilder(org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaderJDOMFactory,%20org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXHandlerFactory,%20org.jdom2.JDOMFactory)) or by setting the `JDOMFactory` [after you have constructred it with `setJDOMFactory(...)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html#setJDOMFactory(org.jdom2.JDOMFactory))

Comment: There are two different reasons we had for subclassing JDOM classes. GMLDatei (subclasses Document): We did not know about the XMLOutputter while designing the class diagram and now, it is too late to change things up

Comment: GMLKnoten (subclasses Element): When using JDOMs getChild- and getChildren-Methods, we always get null as a return although the child we want to get exists.

Comment: @vatbub - the most common reason for not getting the children you expect is because they are not in the namespace you are querying with. You will always need to use a namespace parameter when querying for child elements that are in a namespace.