# Pass a parent instance to a child's type variable in swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass an instance of a parent class to a variable whose type is a subclass of this parent.

There are two classes as follow:

```
class Parent{
    var aaa:String?
    var bbb:String?
    init(pa:String?,pb:String?){
        self.aaa=pa
        self.bbb=pb
    }
}

class Child:Parent{
    var ccc:String?
}
```

Now, I use them like this:

```
let p=Parent(a:"1111",b:"22222")
if let c=p as? Child{
   print(c)
}
```

But the variable is nil in any cases.

I would like to get the result as follow: `c.aaa="1111" c.bbb="222" c.ccc=nil` or other

Comment: sometimes display: could not cast value of type  'parent' to 'child'

Comment: fyi, I suggest you name your classes Parent & Child, as you should not have types starting with a lowercase string

Comment: You cannot cast a superclass instance to a subclass type: the superclass contains a subset of properties of the subclass, in which case a given superclass instance does not hold sufficient information to directly convert into a subclass object. See e.g. [the following Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass) for details.

Comment: In respect to your question, the if let condition would never succeed as **p** is an instance of _parent_, not _child_ so the cast would fail.

Comment: but in this way.how can i got the result i need?

Comment: just like this ?  let c.aaa=p.aaa  let c.bbb=p.bbb? if i have lots of varies.i need write thousand line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all let's clean up your code

```
class Parent {
    var a:String?
    var b:String?
    init(a:String?, b:String?) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}

class Child: Parent{
    var c: String?
}
```

### Answer

With this code you create a Parent object and you put it into the `parent` constant.

```
let parent = Parent(a:"1111",b:"22222")
```

Then you try to cast parent as Child. But `Parent` is **NOT** a `Child`. So the cast will fail.

```
if let child = parent as? Child {
    print(child)
}
```

### Conclusion

```
class Child: Parent { ...}
```

you are saying that a `Child` is also a `Parent`.

**NOT** that a `Parent` is a `Child`.

### Update

If you want to create a `Child` object using a `Parent` object (if this makes sense for your business logic) here's the code

```
class Child: Parent{
    var c: String?

    init(parent:Parent, c:String) {
        super.init(a: parent.a, b: parent.b)
        self.c = c
    }        
}

let parent = Parent(a: "a", b: "b")
let child = Child(parent: parent, c: "c")
child.a // "a"
child.b // "b"
child.c // "c"
```

### `has-a` instead of `is-a`

Another possible solution is avoiding subclassing, here's the code

```
struct Parent {
    var a:String?
    var b:String?
}

struct Child {
    var c: String?
    var parent: Parent
}
```

Now `Child` is not a `Parent` but contains a `Parent`

> You probably should rename them

Now given a parent

```
let parent = Parent(a: "a", b: "b")
```

you can easily create a Child

```
let child = Child(c: "c", parent: parent)
```

And this is how you use the child

```
child.parent.a // "a"
child.parent.b // "b"
child.c // "c"
```

Comment: but in this way.how can i got the result i need?just like this ? let c.aaa=p.aaa let c.bbb=p.bbb? if i have lots of varies.i need write thousand line? –

Comment: @RonnieLee: So you want to copy `aaa` and `bbb` from a `Child` object to a `Parent` object?

Comment: no, i want to copy aaa and bbb from a parent object to child

Comment: @RonnieLee: Sorry, my mistake in my previous comment. Besides manually copying that values you could create an `init` inside `Child` that accept a `Parent` object. I'm going to add the code.

Comment: :)thank you for your help! i think if manually copying when there are lots of varies in this class. it's  a so hard work!

Comment: i see,thanjk you .i try it advence. but this method is also like manually copy.if i have  lots of varies what can i do ？

Comment: super.init(a: parent.a, b: parent.b, c:parent.c, d:parent.d...etc....)?

Comment: @RonnieLee: The problem is that if you have a `Parent` object you __can't__ cast it to `Child`. Casting doesn't work this way. You explicitly need to create the `Child` object and populate it's properties.

Comment: especially ,the parent class have same name variable. i think it should have a good way to do this

Comment: @RonnieLee: I added another way of doing it, please take a look.

Comment: right!!!!!!!!!!!!!can i use it like class? i mean class Parent{...} class child{ var c:string, var parent:Parent}

Comment: @RonnieLee: Yes you can use class too. In this case you'll need to manually define the initializers though.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in response to your question will tell you why your conditional cast will always fail. To print out the value of **c** as an instance of **Child**, the following should work:

```
class Parent {
    var aaa:String?
    var bbb:String?

    init(aaa: String?, bbb: String?) {
        self.aaa = aaa
        self.bbb = bbb
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    var ccc:String?
}

var child = Child(aaa: "", bbb: "")
print(child)
```

Comment: Assuming the naming _aaa_, _bbb_ and _ccc_ are just examples and not your normal naming strategy! :)

Comment: thanks for your help .this just example .but this result is not i need .i want to copy aaa and bbb from a parent object to a child object