# Android: cannot cast BitmapDrawable to a ClipDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-4.3-jelly-bean, bitmapdrawable

I'm trying to implement a simple ClipDrawable using Android Jellybean (SDK 18). I don't understand why I'm getting the casting error for ImageView.getDrawable() when that returns a Drawable, not a BitmapDrawable

Here's my relevant code in the onCreate() of an activity:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guage_one);
    ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    drawable.setLevel(10000);
```

Why would I get a ClassCastException for this? I know BitmapDrawable and ClipDrawable are subclasses of Drawable so you can't cast them to one another, I know that. But why is image.getDrawable() returning a BitmapDrawable and not just a drawable? Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, why not use image.getDrawable to feed the constructor for ClipDrawable?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClipDrawable does not inherit BitmapDrawable.

This is it's inheritance tree:

java.lang.Object

↳ android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

↳ android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper

↳ android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable

To convert a BitmapDrawable to ClipDrawable you can do the following:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guage_one);
ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(image.getDrawable(), Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Ah ok I see I was trying to trying to cast from a superclass to a subclass. So my question is still why is image.getDrawable() returning a BitmapDrawable when in the documentation it says it returns a Drawable? Or am I expecting to much granularity from the documentation since a BitmapDrawable is a Drawable?

Comment: The reason you are getting it is that the resource that was set in the ImageView is an image and was converted by the OS to a BitmapDrawable (if you chose a different resource, you could have received a different type of Drawable from your ImageView, for example ColorDrawable if the resource id was pointing to a color).

Comment: @M.Smith BitmapDrawable is a Drawable, so it's a valid thing to return. This is how Java works. I'm not sure why you find this mysterious

Comment: @Karakuri lol I didn't know why/how it was returning as a BitmapDrawable. That was all