# Why would this give me a ClassCastException in Java, while it works well in C++?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, casting, runtime-error

Something is driving me crazy.

Assume we have these simple classes

```
public class Animal {
public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("From Animal");
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("From Dog");
}

public void flip() {
    System.out.println("Flipped");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Animal a= new Animal();
  ((Dog)a).makeSound(); // Gives me an error at runtime.    

}
```

C++ code:

```
class Animal {
   public: 
          virtual void makeSound(){ cout<<" From Animal";}
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    public : void makeSound(){ cout<<" From Dog ";}
             void  flip() { cout<<"Flipped";}
};

 main() {
Animal *a = new Animal();
((Dog*)a)->makeSound(); // returns From animal 

  }
```

Why would it generate runtime error in Java, while it would work without a problem in C++ ?

Thank you

Comment: It does "work without a problem". It is undefined behaviour due to C legacy.

Comment: a Dog is an Animal BUT an Animal is not necessarily a Dog

Comment: Possibly duplicates [explicit casting from super class to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass) with the same example

Comment: Maybe some people would use the same example since it is everywhere on Java or C++ tutorial websites, but just playing with the same example in Java and C++, I found that I get an error in Java, while no error in C++ and it executes without a problem

Comment: I repeat. The C++ code has problem. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NickyC You mean the code I provided above ? Or in general ?

Can we say that for Downcasting, both languages behave differently ?

Comment: @NickyC Okay I google it and found that C/C++ has some weird things. Not only in downcast, but also in memory access etc..

So we can say that this problem is just a fault from C++ and not that I misunderstood something.

Comment: Stop using the term "C/C++"

Comment: @ZikoUdeM It's not the fault of C++.  C-style casts just don't do any runtime type checking.  Use `dynamic_cast` if you want that.

Comment: @ZikoUdeM I repeat, it is C legacy. It is not a fault from C++. The fault is you mixing C-style cast with C++ polymorphic code. The fault is you choosing the wrong kind of casting.

Comment: The `((Dog*)a)` is equality with `static_cast<Dog*>(a)` in the c++ code,it's not check the run-time type,but the `((Dog)a)` will check the static type and run-time type at run-time,just like dynamic_cast in c++.

Comment: By doing `(Dog*)` you *explicitly* told the compiler not to complain even if you were doing something wrong.

Comment: So it works (but not really) in C++. It wouldn't work well in Object COBOL, would it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example does not work fine; it's behavior is undefined.

C++ has several different types of cast operations.  The one you've used here is a [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (technically it ends up doing a [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)).  C-style casts don't do any runtime type checking.  It's up to the programmer to make sure the types involved make sense.  If you want runtime type checking, use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).  When using `dynamic_cast` with pointers, the cast will fail and return `nullptr` if the object isn't actually an instance of the type being cast to.  When using references it will throw `std::bad_cast`.

```
class Animal {
public: 
    virtual void makeSound() { std::cout << "From Animal\n"; }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    void makeSound() { std::cout << "From Dog\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Animal *a = new Animal();
    Dog* d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(a);
    if (d == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "cast failed\n";
    } else {
        d->makeSound();
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c4df8795a198170)

Answer (score 0):

Downcasting is only possible (in Java) if at some point in your code you reference the child class e.g.

```
Animal a = new Dog(); 
((Dog)a).makeSound();
```

Comment: any explanation for the downvote would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Normally this works because we now that a is a dog, but has Animal's methods only.

While doing a downcast here, we get access to Dog's methods too.

So makeSound() in both cases if called on a directly before and after downcasting will always return From Dog.

P.S: I wouldn't down vote since I don't have a lot of reputation. But I appreciate your answer !