# Mapped Superclass

Tags: android

I need to mapped a model object, which extends into the object to be inizialized.

Example:

```
class User{
}
class RequestUser extends User{
}

void main(){
    User user = new User();
    RequestUser reqUser = user;
}
```

Is there a way to do it native ?, or should I use an external library?
Which do you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this link -> [explicit casting from super class to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass).

If you instantiate a new UserRequest, it will have UserRequest and User properties, UserRequest extends User.
Maybe you should do this:

```
class User{
    int id;
    String name;
}
class RequestUser extends User{
    int requestCode;
}

public void teste(){
    User user = new RequestUser() {{
        id = 0;
        name = "User1";
    }};
    RequestUser reqUser = (RequestUser)user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why "RequestUser" must be a class? It should be a instance of User.

Comment: This answer is slightly low quality. It could have been added as a comment.

Comment: User it is a model, and RequestUser it's other model extended of User.
I need instance new RequestUser with User data, i need mapped a superclass.
it is understood?

Comment: Cant use initiate you "User" as a "RequestUser"?

Comment: @cosmoonot, i'm sorry, but I cant comment in the question, I need to have a 50 reputation to comment

Comment: User have your propertys, and UserRequest have user's propertys and more.
I need instance new UserRequest with full properties that the class User has.
In other languages exist mapped for it. In android, ¿do yo know how do?