# How to remove a lot of duplicate code when extracting from almost identical tables if i use myBatis

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Im use myBatis for work with myMysql. I have several identical tables (actors, producers, composers end etc..) that contain only two fields - id and name.

I have to write a lot of almost identical code to work with this. For example mapper

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="ru.common.mapper.NamedEntityMapper">

    <resultMap id="actor" type="Actor">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getActorByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="actor">
        SELECT * FROM actors WHERE name = #{name}
    </select>
    <select id="getActorById" parameterType="String" resultMap="actor">
        SELECT * FROM actors WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>
    <insert id="saveActor" useGeneratedKeys="true" parameterType="Actor" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO actors (name) VALUES (#{name})
    </insert>

    <resultMap id="writer" type="Writer">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getWriterByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="writer">
        SELECT * FROM writers WHERE name = #{name}
    </select>
    <select id="getWriterById" parameterType="String" resultMap="writer">
        SELECT * FROM writers WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>
    <insert id="saveWriter" useGeneratedKeys="true" parameterType="Writer" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO writers (name) VALUES (#{name})
    </insert>

</mapper>
```

As can be seen in the mapper, very similar methods and queries that differ only in the name of the table and the type being returned. In reality, there are more such methods and it looks awful.

And it is a interface

```
public interface NamedEntityMapper {

    Actor getActorById(long id);
    Actor getActorByName(String name);
    void saveActor(Actor actor);

    Writer getWriterById(long id);
    Writer getWriterByName(String name);
    void saveWriter(Writer writer);
}
```

I tried to do it like this, I made a common interface for each similar model. (BaseModel)

```
public interface BaseModel {
    int getId();
    void setId(int id);
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

And implemented this interface in all models used like Actor...

But this led to failure because it is not clear how to explain to the mapper to create an instance of the desired class. How to transfer type which needs to be created in a xml mapper?

Something like that

```
public interface NamedEntityMapper<T extends BaseModel> {

    T getEntityById(long id, String tableName, Class clazz);

}
```

and xml mapper

```
<mapper namespace="ru.common.mapper.NamedEntityMapper">

    <resultMap id="entity" type="${clazz}">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getEntityById" parameterType="String" resultMap="entity">
        SELECT * FROM ${tableName} WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>    
</mapper>
```

But I could not pass the return type as a parameter to the mapper. This can be done ? This will allow to remove a lot of duplicate code in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mybatis (as of version 3.3.5) has no elegant way to solve this.

You can eliminate some duplication using technics described below but

1. not all
2. by the cost of the code complication.

### CrudMapper

You can try to (somewhat) get rid of duplication in mapper interface by defining generic mapper like this:

```
interface CrudMapper<T> {
   T getById(int id);
   T getByName(String name);
   void create(T);
   void update(T);
}
```

And then use it to define individual mappers for entities:

```
interface AuthorMapper extends CrudMapper<Author> {}

interface WriterMapper extends CrudMapper<Writer> {}
```

### Discriminator with xml

You can also try to use [discriminator](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#discriminator) to reuse result map:

```
<resultMap id="workerResult" type="Worker">
  <id property="id" column="id" />
  <result property="name" column="name"/>
  <discriminator javaType="string" column="worker_type">
    <case value="author" resultType="Author"/>
    <case value="writer" resultType="Writer"/>
  </discriminator>
</resultMap>
```

But it requires to complicate the query namely to add the new column `worker_type` to every select query:

```
<select id="getByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="workerResult">
    SELECT 'actor' as worker_type, id, name FROM actors WHERE name = #{name}
</select>
```

Unfortunately there is no way to avoid creation of individual methods in xml mapper. The only thing you can do is to use velocity macros to have query in one place (namely in velocity macro). In this case method can look like this:

```
<select id="getByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="workerResult">
    #select_by_name('actor')
</select>
```

And macro would be:

```
#macro(select_by_name $worker_table)
   SELECT '${worker_table}' as worker_type, id, name FROM ${worker_table}s WHERE name = @name
```

### Discriminator in Java API

Java API may be better in this regard but not without its own downsides.

```
public interface HierarchyMapper<T> {
    @SelectProvider(method = "buildGetByName", type = HierarchySqlBuilder.class)
    @Results(id = "workerResult", value = {
              @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true),
              @Result(property = "name", column = "name")
            })
    @TypeDiscriminator(cases = {
            @Case(type = Actor.class, value = "actor"),
            @Case(type = Writer.class, value = "writer")},
            column = "worker_type")
    T getByName(@Param("name") String name, @Param("table") String table);
}

@Mapper
public interface ActorMapper extends HierarchyMapper<Actor> {
}

public class HierarchySqlBuilder {
  public static String buildGetByName(
          @Param("name") String name, @Param("table") String table) {
        return String.format(
                "SELECT '%s' as worker_type, id, name from %s where name = #{name}", table, table);
      }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know the way to avoid passing `table` into the mapper. The problem here is that in this case we need to build dynamic query and the entity type (or table) is the parameter. Somewhere the dispatch should happen. One way is to have a repository layer above mappers which would do this dispatch like this:

```
class WorkerRepository {
    @Autowired ActorMapper actorMapper;
    @Autowired WriterMapper writerMapper;

    public Actor getActorByName(String name) {
        return actorMapper.getByNae(name, 'actor');
    }

    public Writer getWriterByName(String name) {
        return writerMapper.getByNae(name, 'writer');
    }
}
```

You may want to reconsider the problem. Given that all classes have the same fields you can store all data in one table and have a discriminator column like `worker_type` in that table to know the actual type of the object. In this case you avoid the problem altogether as you have one table, but still can get different classes in Java (probably having the common parent).

### spring-data-mybatis

One thing you can try is [spring-data-mybatis](https://github.com/hatunet/spring-data-mybatis). It allows to annotate the entity:

```
@Entity
class Actor extends LongId {
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Writer extends LongId {
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then define repository classes which are basically spring data repositories:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
  List<Author> findByName(String name);    
}

public interface WriterRepository extends CrudRepository<Writer, Long> {
  List<Writer> findByName(String name);    
}
```

In this case you do not create mappers manually at all and use `CrudRepository` in clients which used mybatis mappers before. 
`CrudRepository` gives basic crud and additional automatically generated methods based on the method signature. For more details see spring-data [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: Tnanks for answer @Roman Konoval 
To avoid unnecessary complication of the code, I left it as is.

Answer (score -1):

If all the model classes you're using (Actor, Writer, and etc.) have the same attributes (id, name), then you have the right idea in creating a common model for it. But instead of interface, create a common class for it. From what I understand, the *type* of resultMap or *resultType* can only be of primitive type or an object that it can be mapped to, so interface won't work. Then you use the common class (e.g. BaseModel) as the type for your **resultMap** tag and all the *resultMap* attributes pointing to its id.

```
<resultMap id="base" type="BaseModel">
  <id property="id" column="id"/>
  <result property="name" column="name"/>
</resultMap>
<select id="getActorByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="base">
  SELECT * FROM actors WHERE name = #{name}
</select>
```

If there is no difference at all in your model classes, then I suggest you use only the **BaseModel** and remove the other ones. Otherwise, you can have them extend **BaseModel** and when getting the returned object of the mapper, have it cast to the subtype.

**Note:** To avoid getting a *ClassCastException*, you must add an if statement to check the `instanceof` of the returned **BaseModel** object before downcasting it. See this link for details: [explicit casting from super class to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass)

```
BaseModel baseModel = namedEntityMapperImpl.getActorById(id);
if (baseModel instanceof Actor) {
    Actor actor = (Actor)baseModel;
}
```

Comment: I still have a little rating to put a plus, but I really thank you for the answer.

Unfortunately, I can't do cast types (baseModel -> Actor), because the baseModel object is not an extends Actor. 
if (baseModel instanceof Actor) {
    Actor actor = (Actor)baseModel;
} 
This expression will always be false.

Comment: Okay but is there any difference in your model classes? For example, Actor class has its own specific attributes and methods? If not, then you can just do what I mentioned about just using the BaseModel for everything and forget about the other model classes since they're just all the same.

Comment: Tnanks @Stanley Yu i am think about this, but it is no object relation model.
In the future, it may be necessary to switch to Hibernate, for example, and this does not fit with the ideology, one table, one model.