# Why can't I downcast this object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, casting, downcast

I have this method:

```
    private Message getMessage(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    CommandEnum caption = CommandEnum.valueOf(in.readUTF());
    BasicMessage inputMessage;
    if (caption.equals(CommandEnum.BEGIN) || caption.equals(CommandEnum.FILEADDRESS)
            || caption.equals(CommandEnum.CONTAINNAMESERVER))
        inputMessage =  new AddressMessage(caption,in.readUTF(),in.readInt());
    if (caption.equals(CommandEnum.CONTAINFILE) || caption.equals(CommandEnum.DONTCONTAINFILE)
            || caption.equals(CommandEnum.WANTFILE))
        inputMessage =  new FileMessage(caption,in.readUTF());
    else
        inputMessage = new BasicMessage(caption);
    in.readUTF();
    return inputMessage;
}
```

The signature states that the method return `Message`, an object I've created. Notice that in some cases it returns `AddressMessage`, another object of mine that extends `Message`.

My problem - in case i return new `AddressMessage(arguments)` I can't downcast it later to
be an `AddressMessage` object [writing `(AddressMessage) object`]

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't downcast it later"? Why not? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, if what you have is an AddressMessage, then it can be always be downcasted as such.

What I expect is more a logic mistake. That you actually try to downcast an instance of another class. Just try to debug that place or print `obj.getClass()` just to verify what class you are actually trying to downcast.

You can also use `if (my_message instanceof AddressMessage) ...` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

if (object.instanceOf(AddressMessage))... something like this?
look here: [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should really use brackets in your if-else constructs, otherwise only the next statement is used as "then" clause, which can be confusing.

This is what your code looks like with brackets:

```
BasicMessage inputMessage;
if (SNIP1) {
    inputMessage =  new AddressMessage(caption,in.readUTF(),in.readInt());
}
if (SNIP2) {
    inputMessage =  new FileMessage(caption,in.readUTF());
} else {
    inputMessage = new BasicMessage(caption);
}
in.readUTF();
return inputMessage;
```

you'll either get a FileMessage (SNIP2 = TRUE) or a BasicMessage (SNIP2 = FALSE), nothing else.

Edit: an "else if (SNIP2)" instead of "if (SNIP2)" will solve your problem, but you should **really** use brackets