# Overloading methods using derived class objects referenced by base class - java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

```
class base{}

class childA extends base{}

class childB extends base{}
```

I have two functions (overloaded)
like this:

```
function(childA,childA){}

function(childA,childB){}
```

//main program

```
base a = new childA();
base b = new childB();

function(a,b);   
function(a,a);  //problem
```

The function calls won't compile obviously.

But is there a way to get the same effect without complicating the code too much or type checking each time the functions are called.

Note: The overloaded functions are independent of the classes. The classes are just data structures, I would rather not have any interdependent code in them.

PS. I went through quite a few topics covering similar problems, but they don't seem to address the problems mentioned above. Sorry if I missed something, (newbie, first post etc :)).

Edit :

Seems my example was a bit vague, I just wanted to understand the concept in general instead of just a solution to the immediate problem. Seems strange that the above code doesn't work, would have been a powerful feature if it did.

Ok another example, this is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

```
class Shape{}

class Rectangle extends Shape{
//rectangle data
}

class Circle extends Shape{
//circle data
}
```

Overloaded functions (members of another class)

```
boolean checkIntersection(Rectangle r, Circle c){}
boolean checkIntersection(Circle c, Circle c){}
```

//main program

```
Vector<Shape> shapes = new Vector<Shape>();
shapes.add(new Rectangle());
shapes.add(new Circle());
shapes.add(new Circle());

checkIntersection(shapes.get(0),shapes.get(1));
checkIntersection(shapes.get(1),shapes.get(2));
```

Comment: Additionally, the Java standard is to use UpperCamelCase when naming classes.

Comment: knew that..but it hasn't really become second nature. I use it only when I'm coding something seriously.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your method takes a `childA` or `childB` object as argument and you give it a `base` object instead

change the method signature to take the base class as argument like so would fix the problem but you lose the polymorphism

```
function(base a,base b){}
```

what you can do instead is change the variables `a` and `b` to

```
childA a = new childA();
childB b = new childB();
```

Maybe you should have a look at method override instead of overload if you want to hold onto using base instead of childA or childB.

you define a method in base

```
someMethod(){
  //do something
}
```

and then override it in your child classes like

```
@override
someMethod(){
  //do something specific to childA
}
```

then when you do

```
base a = new childA();
```

and call

```
a.doSomething();
```

it will call the overrided method in childA

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote it twice?

Comment: wouldn't that defeat the purpose of overloading ? About sharing an interface could you elaborate, please ?

Comment: im sorry, deleted my post because my answer was plain wrong, should be better now

Comment: Overloading is mainly used in Java to account for optional parameters (in my experience). This often results in the creation of what are known as helper methods.

Comment: The problem you would have with having the generic `function(Base arg0, Base arg1)` is now you have manage casting objects down if you want to use subclass functionality.

Comment: Actually I have an array of base class references pointing to derived class objects, (not just a and b) so I can't change the variable type. Either I will have to check their types and cast them or.. is there another way?

Comment: maybe you should tell what you exactly want to achieve with this polymorphism and childclasses

Comment: like explaining the purpose of base, childA and childB

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
class user9
{
    static class base
    {
    }

    static class childA extends base
    {
    }

    static class childB extends base
    {
    }

    static void function ( childA a , childB b )
    {
    }

    static void function ( childA a1  , childA a2 )
    {
    }

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        childA a = new childA ( ) ;
        childB b = new childB (  ) ;
        function ( a , b ) ;
        function ( a , a ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Base{};

class ChildA extends Base{};
class ChildB extends Base{};

public class JavaTest {

    public static void function( ChildA a, ChildA a2 ) {
        //do something
    }

    public static void function( ChildA a, ChildB b ) {
        //do something else
    }

    public static void function( Base a, Base a2 ) {
        //do something
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        function( new ChildA(), new ChildA() );
        function( new ChildA(), new ChildB() );
        function( new ChildB(), new ChildA() ); //Uses function(Base, Base)
    }
}
```

Here's sample code that uses the 2 overloads you specify, and the generic-fied overload @Ben suggested. As mentioned in my comment, you have to cast down when using the generic overload if you want to use specific ChildA/B functions.

Comment: Thanks, this is how I've implemented it currently. What I wanted to know is,if there is a way to let the compiler figure it out without explicitly checking the type and down casting, seems its not possible :(

Comment: You should check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).