# How to get some information from Set<Defect> in w3c validator

Tags: w3c, w3c-validation, java

How I can get some information (column, line, message) at this code?

```
String xhtml = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!<p></body></html>";
ValidationResponse response = new ValidatorBuilder().html().validate(xhtml);
if (!response.valid()) 
{
    Set<Defect> errors = response.errors();
    //... what write at this place?
    System.out.println(errors[0].column() + " " + errors[0].source());
}
```

I tried to write as:

```
String xhtml = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!<p></body></html>";
ValidationResponse response = new ValidatorBuilder().html().validate(xhtml);
 if (!response.valid()) 
 {
     Set<Defect> errors = response.errors();
     Defect[] errorsArray = (Defect[]) errors.toArray();
     System.out.println(errorsArray[0].column() + " " + errorsArray[0].source());
 }
```

But get exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.rexsl.w3c.Defect;
>       at HTMLValidator.main(HTMLValidator.java:17)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downcasting in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`toArray()` returns a `Object[]`. If you want a `Defect[]`, you should use the overloaded version:

```
String xhtml = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!<p></body></html>";
ValidationResponse response = new ValidatorBuilder().html().validate(xhtml);
if (!response.valid()) 
{
    Set<Defect> errors = response.errors();
    Defect[] errorsArray = errors.toArray(new Defect[errors.size()]);
    System.out.println(errorsArray[0].column() + " " + errorsArray[0].source());
}
```