# Calling method By reference type

Tags: java

In the below code in **Animal Class** when I remove the **ClimbTrees()** Method why is it generating Error

```
public class Refr1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
      Animal objChimp = new Chimp();
      objChimp.ClimbTrees();     
    }
}


class Animal
{
    void ClimbTrees()
    {
     System.out.println("I am Animal Which Climb Tree");    
    }
}


class Chimp extends Animal 
{
    void ClimbTrees()
    {
        System.out.println("I am Chimp Which Climb Tree");  
    }
}
```

If I Remove the **ClimbTrees()** in Animal Class its showing Below Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method ClimbTrees() is undefined for the type Animal
```

Comment: Obviously, because you are calling the method you just removed, in your main method. You need to read up on how method overriding works (hint, the method may be defined in `Chimp`, but the object in your main class is an `Animal`).

Comment: But it is still in Chimp class right

Comment: @JavaBeginner - if you want to call a method that only exists in a  class, then you need to declare your object as that class type.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But when I create object with Chimp Reference I can call method which is not in Animal Class but in chimp class. At this stage is  still polymorphism in code

Comment: @JavaBeginner - please see the link i added in my answer

Comment: @JavaBeginner last case you ask is not polymorphism, since you need to know the exact child and make a downcasting in order to call the method.

Comment: Plz correct me.In Animal objChimp = new Chimp(); the objChimp creation happens at compile time and its assignment new Chimp() happens at run time right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you will get - The method ClimbTrees() is undefined for the type Animal. 
Why does it happen ?

The compiler checks the static type of objChimp. It is animal. The dynamic type of objChimp is Chimp.

The compiler first checks if there is a method called ClimbTrees() in the static type of objChimp. If it does not find it, then it throws an error. But, when you don't remove the method, the compiler sees the static type and finds ClimbTrees(). Only when it finds that, it will let you compile your code. During run time, its checked if there is also a ClimbTrees() in the dynamic type of objChimp. If found, then execute the ClimbTrees() of chimp and not of animal. If not found, then execute ClimbTrees() of static type of objChimp, that is ClimbTrees() of Animal (comment the climb trees of chimp and see what happens).

Notes -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

Comment: Plz correct me.In Animal objChimp = new Chimp(); the objChimp creation happens at compile time and its assignment  new Chimp() happens at run time right

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> when I remove the ClimbTrees() Method why is it generating Error
> ```

Its simply because using the `objChimp` instance you can call the methods in `Animal` class. Since `ClimbTrees()` method is not in `Animal` class you are getting this error.

**Edit:**
I think you are trying to learn overriding and Polymorphism. You should get more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). In your case below is true. Am not explaining you the WHY factor in below examples I will leave it for your research.

```
// a. You can call only methods/variables is Animal class using objChimp instance
// b. If you are calling overridden methods, the method in Chimp class will be called in run time
Animal objChimp = new Chimp();

// a. You can call methods/variables both in Animal class and Chimp class using objChimp instance
// b. If you are calling overriden methods, the method in Chimp class will be called in runtime
Chimp objChimp = new Chimp();
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But when I create object with Chimp Reference I can call method which are not in Animal Class. At this stage there is no polymorphism in code

Comment: I understand when you say "method which are not in Animal Class." it means the methods in Chimp class. Is it right?. If you are saying yes, that method call is nothing to do with polymorphism, its just invoking a method in a class.

Comment: Yes Methods in Chimp class but not in animal Class

Comment: Yeah. In that case the method call has nothing to do with Polymorphism. Its Just another method call in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `objChimp` is declared from `Animal` type, you can only use the `Animal` attributes/methods which you have access. If you want to call a specific attribute/method from a child, you should downcast it. This can make your code work (assuming you deleted `ClimbTrees` method from `Animal` class):

```
Animal objChimp = new Chimp();
((Chimp)objChimp).ClimbTrees();
```

However, you must be sure you can downcast the class to the specific class. Check  [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/380813/1065197) for more info.