# Trying to understand casting and dynamic binding in terms of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, dynamic-binding

Let's say I have a GrandParentClass that gets inherited by ParentClass which gets inherited by ChildClass.

Why can I only cast "up the chain" but not down?

Why can I only dynamic bind "down the chain" but not up?

I'm looking for some reasoning I can apply to these questions instead of just memorizing the pattern. I'm really hoping this isn't just a "that's just the way it is" kind of answer.

Example of casting:

```
ParentClass object = new ParentClass();
System.out.println((GrandParentClass)object);  //casting ChildClass throws compiler error
```

Example of dynamic binding:

```
GrandParentClass = new ChildClass(); //Switching GrandParentClass with ChildClass throws run time error.
```

Comment: Possibly for the same reason there is not multiple-inheritance? (because it quickly becomes unmanageable)

Comment: For the casting question here is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general reasoning for these casting rules (not only in Java) is that inheritance allows you build trees of classes, not just lists. To put it differently, not every object of type `GrandParentClass` is necessarily an object of type `ParentClass` and not every object of type `ParentClass` is necessarily of type `ChildClass`. You could conceive an alternative `ParentClass2` inheriting from `GrandParentClass` or simply instantiate an object of type `GrandParentClass`. Imagine what would happen if you were allowed to access a `GrandParentClass` object as if it was a `ChildClass` object with all the methods and variables that are defined only in `ChildClass` but not above. There is no meaningful resolution.

So, casting "up the chain" always makes sense, since the inheritance relation is known at compile-time. Your dynamic binding example is the same thing; You are binding "up the chain" (not at all "down the chain") since you are assigning a derived type object to a reference of a type it was derived from.

Comment: I was slightly confused about you saying dynamic binding is still "up the chain" but combined with smerny's answer that totally makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Might be easy to think about it as animals. Lets say the grandparent class is `Animal`, the parent class is `Dog`, and the child class is `GermanShepherd`.

Your first example would be as such:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
System.out.println((Animal)dog);  
//casting GermanShepherd throws compiler error
```

A dog can always be an animal, but a dog might not always be a german shepherd (it might be a poodle).

Your second example:

```
Animal animal = new GermanShepherd(); 
//Switching Animal with GermanShepherd throws run time error.
```

Similarly, a GermanShepherd will always be an animal, but an animal might not be a GermanShepherd (could be a turtle).

Answer (score 0):

ParentClass has the method `getWidget`; ChildClass has the inherited method `getWidget` and declared a new method `getAnotherWidget`.  This means that when the compiler sees that you have a `ChildClass` object, it knows that `ChildClass` can do everything that `ParentClass` can do, therefore it's safe to treat `ChildClass` as a `ParentClass`.  However, when the compiler sees a `ParentClass`, it *doesn't* know that `ParentClass` has a `getAnotherWidget` method - you can determine this at runtime (via e.g. `instanceof ChildClass`), or at compile time you can tell the compiler "this ParentClass object is really a ChildClass - trust me, I know what I'm doing" by performing a cast `ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass)parentClass` - if you're wrong then you'll get a `ClassCastException`.  You need to perform this cast even if `ChildClass` merely inherited from `ParentClass` without adding any more methods - the compiler is not clever enough to know that the `ChildClass` is basically equivalent to a `ParentClass`.

Dynamic binding only works one way because the `ParentClass` does not know all of its children - you might load additional inheriting classes at runtime.  In contrast, `ChildClass` knows who its `ParentClass` is, and so it can override `ParentClass`'s methods.  (This is why `ChildClass` can call `super.getWidget()` but `ParentClass` can't call `child.getWidget()` - even if `ParentClass` knew who all of its children were, how would it know which child class you were referring to?  Rather than overburden the syntax, it's simpler for Java to require you to instantiate a `ChildClass` object if you want to use its methods rather than calling them through `ParentClass`)

Comment: What do you mean by "if you're wrong then you'll get an" exception.  Like what makes it correct to be able to cast down?

Comment: If you have `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` that both inherit from `ParentClass`, then you will get a `ClassCastException` if you try to cast a `ChildClass1` to a `ChildClass2` or vice versa, e.g. `ParentClass parentClass = new ChildClass1(); ChildClass2 childClass = (ChildClass2)parentClass;` will throw an exception; this is because `ChildClass2` may have methods that are incompatible with `ChildClass1`

Comment: When you cast an object you're not actually changing the underlying object - that's immutable for the lifetime of the object.  All you're doing is telling the compiler to treat the object as though it belonged to a different class; if you tell it to treat the object as a compatible class (e.g. a parent class or a child class) then everything goes off without a hitch, but if you tell the compiler to treat the object as an incompatible class then you'll get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding and casting go hand in hand. They way I understand it is `ALWAYS` read from right to left to figure out if you can bind and cast... e.g:

`object A`          ←       `object B` 
                           is a