# Java generics inheritance warning

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

The `foo` method in following example gives us a warning, while `bar` not?

```
public class X {

    static class Y {}
    static class Z extends Y {}

    Y y = new Y();

    <T extends Y> T foo() {
        return (T) y; // warning - Unchecked cast from X.Y to T
    }

    Z bar() {
        return (Z) y; // compiles fine
    }

}
```

Comment: How much do you know about type erasure? See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type Erasure

Comment: I think it is clear, that `foo()` should give a warning. You are casting the object `y` to some unknown superclass `T` of `Y`. I am also very interested why `bar()` does not. I guess the compiler is able to see that casting `Y` to `Z` is not causing problems, as the definition of `Z` is available.

Comment: @SebastianH: I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks. This looks much better. Two examples compressed into one. Will remember the formatting when asking questions next time.

Comment: @gudge What I meant was that the cast `(Z) y` will fail. But that has nothing to do with compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type T is erased down to Y at compile time, this how generics work in Java. Thus when the cast is performed at run time the type of T is not available, it is just an `Y` in the byte code.

`bar()` compiles fine as all the type information is available (the cast will fail). But `foo()` lacks this type information and cannot fail, potentially (or certainly, in this case) rendering the type signature of the method incorrect and becoming a source of bugs in the program.

To do this safely you need to pass the class itself to the method.

```
<T extends Y> T foo(Class<T> cls) {
    return cls.cast(y); //No type warning. Will throw an error when cast fails.
}
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot about the extends bit. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because `T` its a type tag and `Z` its a class name. `return (Z) y;` its correct type casting, but `return (T) y;` - casting to unknown type in runtime. JVM nothing known about type tags in runtime (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) tutorial section). In absolutely short, `return (T) y;` *almost* equivalently `return (Object) y;`, it is unchecked cast from `X.Y` to `Object`. Also see about [downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java) for `return (Z) y;` explanation.

Comment: "*`return (T) y;` almost equivalently `return (Object) y;`*" actually since `<T extend Y>` it is equivalent in bytecode to `return (Y) y;`.