# Why dot operator is not used while using findViewById() method?

Tags: android

I am totally new in android.So may be my question will be like very funny for someone but still i should know the answer of my question-

```
TextView tv;

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anyname);
```

This is the code that i write in java for idtentify the resource id from xml file.As i know (TextView) is a object of View class and findViewById() is a method.Here my confusion is arising.
When we invoke any method with the object then we use dot operator(.)-

```
obj1`.methodName()`
```

But for the first case there is no dot operator between object and method.So my question is why?

JavaExperts i really need help and suggestion regrading my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
But for the first case there is no dot operator between object and method.So my question is why?
```

That is what you called down-casting a `View` to `TextView`.

`findViewById` will return a `View` which `textView` inherits from, what it is doing is that it is [down-casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java) the `View` to a `textView` that inherits from it.

Also `(TextView)` is not an object it is a class.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin-I find this article from android official website.Here it is written (TextView) is a object. <View>
An individual UI component, generally referred to as a "widget". Different kinds of View objects include TextView, Button, and CheckBox.

Comment: @user3732316 (TextView) can call its static method but not its public method, and if you create an object from it example. TextView tx ->> now tx is an object of class TextView that can call its public methods.

Comment: refer to the official java tutorial about object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anyname); here you are casting the findViewById to TextView that's why you have written `(TextView)`.