# Class/object Casting

Tags: java, class, classcastexception

I am getting an exception for the following code.

```
class A {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Running foo()");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Overidden foo()");
    }
}

public class Casting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new B();
        obj.foo();

        // B ref = (B) obj;
        // ref.foo();

        B ref = (B) new A();
        ref.foo();
    }
}
```

But if I run

```
B ref = (B) obj;
ref.foo();
```

instead of

```
B ref = (B) new A();
ref.foo();
```

it works properly.

Can anyone explain what is happening here.?

Comment: You're trying to cast A to a B, which it is not.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/380828/2194456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is an instance of `B` because you created it using the contructor of class `B`. This is why `B ref = (B) obj;` works fine.

In `B ref = (B) new A();` you are simply casting an object of type `A` created using the constructor of `A` (which is the parent class) to a subclass type which will cause a `java.lang.ClassCastException`. The opposite casting would work, i.e.

```
A ref = (A) new B();
ref.disp();
```

in which case you converting an instance of a subclass to its parent which is fine since an object of type `B` is also an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to explain.

By doing `new A()` you receive an A-object. Then you tell the JVM it's of type B, but that's obviously wrong and the JVM can't cast from A-type to B-type, how should Java know how to do that? It's not sure that A has the same methods as B. It's just a parent, B could have methods A hasn't. If you could cast from A to B you could have B objects that don't behave like B objects and don't have the B classes methods.

If you have a B-object you can treat it like a A-object because every B-object has at least the same methods, constructors and ivars.

#### An example using ducks:

Imagine you have got an abstract `Duck` class (but you didn't declared it as abstract). This class is the parent class of all other duck classes and also including `RubberDuck`. As reason of that the `Duck` class just has some basic methods like `getSize` but no method like `walk` or `eat` (a rubber duck can't eat herself).

What would happen if you create a `duck` object and downcast it to `BuffleheadDuck` and you would try to invoke the `walk` method? A `BuffleheadDuck` duck knows how to walk, but an abstract duck can't walk.