# what's the difference between the two initialization: Object x = new String(); String x = new String();

Tags: java

what's the difference between the two initialization:

```
Object x = new String(); 
String x = new String();
```

in java

thank!

Comment: An `Object` is not a `String`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Object x = new String(); // pointing to a String and saying - Hey, Look there! Its an Object
 String x = new String();// pointing to a String and saying - Hey, Look there! Its a String
```

More importantly :
The methods of String that can be accessed depend on the reference. For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new String();
    String s = new String();
    o.split("\\."); // compile time error
    s.split("\\."); // works fine

}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no difference in the *initializations*, only in the *declarations* and therefore in the way the rest of your code sees the variables type.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object x = new String();
```

here, `x` has access only to the `Object`'s methods and members.
(To use `String` members, you have to typecast the `x` to `String` (using [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/380828/2764279)))

```
String x = new String();
```

here, `x` has access to all the methods and members of `Object` as well as `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first option `x` will be considered by the compiler as an Object and in the second it'll be considered as a String. Example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    Object x = new String();
    test(x);
    String y = new String();
    test(y);
    // and you can also "trick" the compiler by doing
    test((String)x);
    test((Object)y);
}

public static void test(String s) {
    System.out.println("in string");
}

public static void test(Object o) {
    System.out.println("in object");
}
```

will print:

```
in object
in string
in string
in object
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are same, X will refer to the string object.

But x variable in `Object x = new String();` need to be Type casted to String , using `x.toString()` or `(String)x` before making use of it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the other answerers, both cases will result in the variable x holding a reference to a String. The only difference is how subsequent code will see the reference: as an Object vs String, i.e. determining which operations the compiler will allow on the reference.

Essentially, the question highlights the difference between a statically typed language (e.g. Java) and a dynamic one (e.g. Python, Javascript, etc.). In the latter you don't have to declare the type of the reference, so the code for this is simply something like:

```
var x = new String();
```

In this case, the compiler infers the type at *runtime*, but you lose some static type checking at *compile time*.

In everyday Java code you will always use the form:

```
String x = new String();
```

since that will allow you to treat x like a String and call, e.g. the method `toUpperCase()` on it. If x were an `Object`, the compiler won't allow you to call that method, only Object methods, e.g. `equals()`.

However, the exact opposite is true in the following case:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

Unless you specifically want to use methods exposed by ArrayList (unlikely), it is always better to declare `list` as a `List`, not `ArrayList`, since that will allow you to change the implementation to another type of List later, without changing the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is you need to cast it a lot
however you can use the same variable and reinitialize it with another type. It is very usefull when you are working with changing variables..

Example:

```
Object x = new String();
if(x instanceof String){
    System.out.println("String");
}
x = new ArrayList<String>();
if(x instanceof ArrayList){
    System.out.println("ArrayList");
}
```

returns:

String
ArrayList