# Hsqldb - Return a Result Set from Stored Proc

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am trying to call a stored procedure in HsqlDB and return a Result Set

My Stored proc is as follows

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE p_getTeamTasksForLastXDays(IN teamId BIGINT, IN numberOfDays BIGINT) READS SQL DATA
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  BEGIN ATOMIC
   declare curs cursor for select taskId, taskName from V_TASK_DETAILS;
   open curs;
  END;
  /;
```

The Java and hibernate code I am using to call this proc is as follows

```
public void getTaskExecutionLogs(Long teamId, Long numberOfDays) {
        LOG.info("Entered getTaskExecutionLogs Method - teamId:{}, numberOfDays: {}", teamId, numberOfDays);

        ProcedureCall procedureCall = currentSession().createStoredProcedureCall("p_getTeamTasksForLastXDays");
        procedureCall.registerParameter( TEAM_ID, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN ).bindValue( teamId );
        procedureCall.registerParameter( NUMBER_OF_DAYS, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN ).bindValue( numberOfDays );

        ProcedureOutputs outputs = procedureCall.getOutputs();
        ResultSetOutput resultSetOutput = (ResultSetOutput) outputs.getCurrent();

        List resultSetList = resultSetOutput.getResultList();

}
```

The error I get when I try to call this proc is as follows

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.result.internal.UpdateCountOutputImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.result.ResultSetOutput
    at com.mct.dao.database.impl.TaskDetailsDAOImpl.getTaskExecutionLogs(TaskDetailsDAOImpl.java:229)
```

The exact same code works ok when I try to call a stored proc in MySql

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Line 229 is - ResultSetOutput resultSetOutput = (ResultSetOutput) outputs.getCurrent();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ProcedureOutputs` is an `interface` which `extends` `Outputs` ([source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/ProcedureOutputs.java)).

`ResultSetOutput` is an `interface` which `extends` `Output` ([source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/result/ResultSetOutput.java)).
When you call `getCurrent()` of `Outputs`, you will get an `Output` ([source](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/result/Outputs.html#getCurrent%28%29)).

Basically, you expected the conversion to be correct, since you convert the result into a sub-interface of `Output`. The thing you are doing is called [downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java). Let's see the case.

You want to cast an object to another. The downcast might be possible, since `ResultSetOutput` `extends` `Output`. Since the downcast might be possible, you do not get a compile time error and when it is possible, such as in the case when you call a stored procedure in MySQL, the downcast will be successful. However, when the downcast is not possible, you get a runtime exception. In our particular case, the downcast is not possible, since `.getOutputs` returns another classification, maybe a sub-interface which is on another inheritance branch, like [UpdateCountOutput](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/result/UpdateCountOutput.html).

Comment: yes that is the case I am experiencing here. The same code works 100% fine with a MySql stored procedure so I want to replicate that proc in Hsqldb for my unit tests

Comment: What does outputs.getCurrent().getClass() return?

Comment: @Damo, if you can find out what is the class of that object, then you will be able to find the solution.

Comment: getCurrent().getClass() returns org.hibernate.result.internal.UpdateCountOutputImpl for the Hsqldb stored proc. For the MySql stored proc, it returns org.hibernate.result.internal.ResultSetOutputImpl

Comment: Also - when run against Mysql stored proc in debug mode - I get the following output - [DEBUG] [194]org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl[buildOutput]  - Building Return [isResultSet=true, updateCount=-1, extendedReturn=false. For the Hsqldb stored proc in debug mode - I get this output - [DEBUG] [194]org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl[buildOutput]  - Building Return [isResultSet=false, updateCount=0, extendedReturn=false

Comment: That UpdateCountOutputImpl looks like being the implementation of UpdateCountOutput, isn't it? If you implement a converter method, then you can call that and if you overload that method to handle the relevant conversion types, then you can use that method at multiple places safely.

Comment: Yeah im not sure if I want to go to that hassle just for testing my stored procs. I have test stored procs that return normal values or update values just fine - the problem is with the result sets

Comment: @Damo, I perfectly understand you, but you either create a converter, or you implement a class for doing the stuff you need. I perfectly understand your frustration due to the fact that your code by itself cannot be used as a standard because the thing you have to use was not well planned, but the solution is to fill the gaps yourself. You will not have a great time while doing so, but after you finished this task, your code will be usable as a standard. If my answer solves your problem, then you might consider marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Lajos is right about the downcast. The problem is that you're coding under the assumption that the `Output` returned by `ProcedureOutputs.getCurrent()` will be a `ResultSetOutput`, when in reality, it may be an `UpdateCountOutput`.

In fact, the `Output` interface has a method `isResultSet()` to help you determine that:

> boolean org.hibernate.result.Output.isResultSet()
>
> Determine if this return is a result (castable to `ResultSetOutput`). The alternative is that it is an update count (castable to `UpdateCountOutput`).
>
> Returns:
>
> `true` indicates that this can be safely cast to `ResultSetOutput`), other wise it can be cast to `UpdateCountOutput`.

In adition to that, `Outputs` can deliver multiple `Output` and the state of `Output.getCurrent()` is controlled by the `Output.goToNext()`.

So, in order to properly handle multiple results, you have to get the outputs with something like this:

```
ProcedureOutputs outputs = procedureCall.getOutputs();

do {
    Output current = outputs.getCurrent();

    if (current.isResultSet()) {
        ResultSetOutput resultSetOutput = (ResultSetOutput) current;
        System.out.println("do something with result set output");
    } else {
        UpdateCountOutput updateCountOutput = (UpdateCountOutput) current;
        System.out.println("do something with update count output");
    }            
} while (outputs.goToNext());

outputs.release();
```

In my tests I get:

> 1647 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - {call p_getTeamTasksForLastXDays(?,?)}
>
> Hibernate: {call p_getTeamTasksForLastXDays(?,?)}
>
> 1668 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl  - Building Return [isResultSet=false, updateCount=0, extendedReturn=false
>
> do something with update count output
>
> 1669 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl  - Building Return [isResultSet=true, updateCount=-1, extendedReturn=false
>
> 1671 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - Result set row: 0
>
> 1671 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - Result row:
>
> do something with result set output

PS: I don't have mysql here, so I cannot confirm if it returns both the `ResultSetOutput` and `UpdateCountOutput` but in different order than hsqldb, but maybe you can verify that.

Comment: Thanks for your assiatance guys - this indeed solved the issue. Looking at the abouve code sample - Hsqldb returned the UpdateCountOutput result first and the ResultSetOutput second. Mysql returned the ResultSetOutput  first and the UpdateCountOutput second

Comment: "Outputs can deliver multiple Output", why a stored procedure will produce multiple outputs?