# when downcasting is possible in java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, downcast

I have a basic question in java. from my research I found out that downcasting is not allowed in java because it throws an exception in runtime but in some limited cases such as [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java)

But I can't understand why this statement proceeds 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection() without problem?

(because `openConnection()` returns a `URLConnection` object )

be specific

I'm sorry for poor english language because i am not a native speaker

Comment: thanks yassin; but under which circumstances it returns true or false

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate of the exact one you mention because the answer is literally the first line in the first answer: "*Downcasting is allowed when there is a possibility that it suceeds at run time*". Contrast this to your statement "*downcasting is not allowed in java because it throws an exception in runtime*" and it seems like a simple mistake in interpretation.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel if it is so why sometimes downcasting throws classcastexception?

Comment: Just because there is a possibility it succeeds doesn't mean there is no possibility it doesn't succeed. Downcasting is allowed when it "may or may not" work and when it doesn't work, you get the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the object returned from url.openConnection in the circumstances it is used here *is* a HttpUrlConnection and the programmer needs access to its methods, but it was returned as an interface, so `javac` has no idea that it is anything else but the interface.

In other words, the programmer breaks the encapsulation design in the API to get access to functionality hidden by the API.

Comment: thank you. can you give some scenario[guidelines] when java has problem with downcasting and when not??

Comment: You must understand the role that _interfaces_ have in Java.  An example: An interface could be a "Car".  You could then have two classes "BMW" and "VW" which each are a Car.  A BMW is not a VM and a VW is not a BMW.  If you have a statement like "Car car = getCar()" it could not return _just_ a Car (because that is the interface) but _must_ return a BMW or a VW (or whatever else you have).  Downcasting means "from now on treat as a".  You cannot treat a VW as a BMW.

Answer (score 0):

`URL.openConnection()` returns a [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), which is an [abstract class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type), i.e. the returned object can never really be of type `URLConnection`, but **must** be of a class that inherits from `URLConnection`, such as [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

As the accepted answer to the Stackoverflow thread you linked to says,

> Downcasting is allowed when there is a possibility that it succeeds at run time:

In this case, it is **guaranteed** to succeed at runtime, because the returned object can not be an instance of the abstract class `URLConnection` as explained above.

Comment: If the class returned was not a HttpUrlConnection (of which there is no guarantee) an exception would be thrown.