# Why Creating an object of Parent class of type sub class is not possible but reverse is possible?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I have read [this-Downcasting is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java) but not got **why actually this is not possible**, below is the code snippet

```
class Parent {

}

public class Inherit  extends Parent{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Inherit()  //No Error
        Inherit sub = new Parent();  // Type mismatch error
    }
}
```

My question is why creating a parent object of type sub class is possible(`Parent a = new Inherit())` but why reverse is not possible? what is the actual reason(Except `type mismatch`)

Comment: Because a superclass might be missing stuff that is defined in the subclass.

Comment: Because every `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Dog` in terms of `class Dog extends Animal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy example:

```
class Parent {
  public String name;
}

class Inherit extends Parent {
  public int age;
}
```

So each `Inherit` has a name but a `Parent` has no age. What is if you call the following:

```
Inherit sub = new Parent();
sub.age; // ERROR: because a parent has no age
```

So it is not possible to assign a parent object to a sub class reference because something could be missing like @OH GOD SPIDERS pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclaimer: Super (over)simplistic intuitive explanation, without getting into proper technical detail.</sub>

I will start by pointing out that downcasting *may* be possible in special cases; specifically, on a "parent" object that was itself created by upcasting a "child" object. Hopefully the reason for this will be clear in a sec.

Say you have a `Parent` object with field `x`.
And a `Child` object which extends this with another field `y`.

When you instantiate a `Parent` object normally, java allocates enough memory to hold `x`.
When you instantiate a `Child` object, java allocates enough memory to hold both `x` and `y`.

When you *upcast* a `Child` object onto a `Parent` one, the memory layout doesn't change; java simply ignores the memory bit that was reserved for `y`, and treates all calls to this object as if it only contained `x`.

But if you were to attempt to *downcast* a `Parent` object into a `Child` one, you would essentially be missing the bit that refers to `y` in the object's memory footprint. Since the intent is one of 'casting' rather than "copying the object somewhere else", casting in this case is not allowed.

In the case the the `Parent` object was originally obtained by upcasting a `Child` object, it is then possible to downcast it back into a `Child` object; java treats this as a special case, since the memory layout would allow it.

This is also the reason that downcasting is treated as a *runtime* bug, rather than a compilation one.

---

<sub>PS. Note that the corollary from this is that when one upcasts at instantiation, while this is treated as a `Parent` object in the code, an entire `Child` object is stored in memory -- which is why a successful downcast back to a `Child` object can reoccur at any time.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Think about the *inherit* relationship. An object of the child class **is** and object of the parent class, it has all its properties and methods, while the inverse is definitely not true.

For example:

```
class Parent{
    public void methodA(){ ... };
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public void methodB(){ ... };
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child p = new Parent();
        p.methodA(); //Ok, parent object has method A
        p.methodB(); // parent object does not have method B, 
                     //but Child class exposes it. what happens here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OPPS concept Inheritance follows **IS-A** relationship between parent and child class which means if `child class (Jeep)` extends the `parent class(vehicle)` then you can say Jeep **IS-A** vehicle but vice-versa is not possible. Suppose `Jeep` class have `wheels` property

```
class Vehicle {
  public Date madeYear;
  public void start(){}
}

class Jeep extends Vehicle {
  public int wheels;
}
```

`Jeep jeep = new Vehicle(); //Its not valid because vehicle object don't have wheels property which you can try to access from jeep reference variable.`