# Conversion of string variable to stringProperty

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am using javafx.
I have to convert a variable of Object type to StringProperty type.

```
Object v = "var";
StringProperty var = (StringProperty) v;
```

I am not getting any compile time error. 
But `java.lang.ClassCastException` shows up.
Thanks

Comment: Object v = "var"; StringProperty var = (StringProperty) var; ... var doesn't exist yet, try with: Object v = "var"; StringProperty var = (StringProperty) v;

Comment: I have tried this thing but getting java.lang.ClassCastException error. @Stultuske

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java

Answer (score 5):

You cannot cast an `Object` containing a `String` value to a `StringProperty`.

But you can instantiate a `StringProperty` from an `Object` containing a `String`:

```
  Object v = "var";
  StringProperty var = new SimpleStringProperty((String) v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why assign a `String` value to an `Object`? , I suggest

```
    String v = "var";
    StringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(v);
```

or

```
    Object v = "var"; // assignment may come from elsewhere
    StringProperty var;
    if (v instanceof String) {
        var = new SimpleStringProperty((String) v);
    }

    else {
        //.. doSomethingElse 
    }
```

this is done just to avoid any kind of exception