# Using child exception class to catch parent class. How is that possible?

Tags: java, exception, java-7

I have following code:

```
1 public static byte[] foo() throws IOException {

    ...

2   try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
3        wr.write(stringObj.getBytes("UTF-8"));
4        wr.flush();
5    } catch (Exception e) {
6        throw e;
7    }

    ...

}
```

The interesting part of this code is, it's allowing parent class to be caught by a child, I am not sure why this is the case, though I also added following few more lines of code to understand it:

**Try 1 (no compile-time error):**

```
1 public static byte[] foo() throws IOException {

    ...

2   try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
3        wr.write(stringObj.getBytes("UTF-8"));
4        wr.flush();

5         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

6    } catch (Exception e) {
7        throw e;
8    }

    ...

}
```

**Try 2 (compile time error at `line 8` but `line 6` worked):**

```
1 public static byte[] foo() throws IOException {

    ...

2   try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
3        wr.write(stringObj.getBytes("UTF-8"));
4        wr.flush();
5    } catch (Exception e) {
6        throw e;
7    }

8    throw new Exception();
    ...

}
```

Also, I know [downcasting is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java) when the type is same at runtime, but then try 1 line 5 worked (maybe at runtime it will fail if ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs)?

> Downcasting is allowed when there is a possibility that it suceeds at run time:
>
> `Object o = getSomeObject();`
>
> `String s = (String) o; // this is allowed because o could reference a String`

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to know that what you catch can only be an IOException (or a runtime exception).

Comment: @JBNizet are you saying that if the line `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();` was replaced with `throw new Exception();`, then the compiler will complain?

Comment: Yup that seems to be the case

Comment: @smac89 can you please provide us with any reference which can justify that.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I appreciate your prompt response to this answer, but I am aware of the concept that you pointed out to be duplicate. But whatever you marked does not seems to be relevant to this question. If so, please elaborate.

Comment: The `IOException` in your question is misleading. Remove it, it doesn't contribute anything to the behavior you see. Then you'll understand the duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exactly that is my point, its miss leading and that why I need the reason, removing it `IOException` and making it similar to other does not answer. It does not make sense why first example compiled successfully but not try 2.

Comment: You're fixating on the `IOException`. Change it to `InterruptedException`, change it to `Throwable`, change it to any other checked exception. It doesn't matter. It's not relevant. The behavior is the same and explained in the duplicates.

Comment: Sure, thanks the other reference you just add seems to be duplicate of this and now it makes sense to close this question.

Comment: I don't need to provide any other reference than what you already have. Take the code you have and replace `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()` with `throw new Exception()`, and you will see that the compiler throws an exception.

Comment: @smac89 I did and it compiled successfully, and that is why I am confused. :)

Comment: @Vishrant, is your method still declared like `public static byte[] foo() throws IOException`?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. This is what I did: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ec9b6e54f37430c7e8c89c02c693da88. If you remove the comment comment for the other exception, there is a compiler error. Maybe I have to try creating something that throws IOException? I will try that too and see if it behaves differently

Comment: Yup just tried with something similar to what you have: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63a5f7385d4eb17bd8191fa3cf278b65. If it helps, here is my compiler version `java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)`