# Java: Different Generic type declaration and instance

Tags: java, generics

I see that you have to use a generic form both when declaring the variable and assigning the instance. The question I want to ask is this:
Is there any case the type of variable and instance can be different?
Like

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use the diamond operator to infer the type on the right:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Is there any case the type of variable and instance can be different?

Generic types in Java are erased at runtime. That means that the *instance* has no generic type. The type only exists at compile-time, on the variable.

The generic types on the left and the right do not have to be exactly the same, but then you have to use wild-cards:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

With these wild-cards, you are then quite limited in what you can still do with the objects. For example, you can only `get` a `Number` out of a `List<? extends Number>`, but you cannot `add` a new `Integer` to it (because it might have been a `List<Double>` for all you know).

This is still useful if you want to write methods that can accept lists of some interface type:

```
boolean areAllPositive(List<? extends Number> numbers) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about wild cards in generics or provide a useful link that I can refer to?

Comment: Maybe start with the official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html