# Why java upcasting causes overwritten girl method to be called?

Tags: java, class, upcasting

I’m trying to understand upcasting with Java. I just created two classes `Mom` and `Girl`, with each having their own constructor (constructors have no parameters).

If I understand, `Mom mom = new Girl()` causes the instance created by `new Girl` to be cast to a `Mom` type, and that is confirmed by the fact that the `Mom` constructor is being called. So `mom` variable is pointing to a `Mom` instance, right? So, why, when I overwrite a `Mom` method `test()` in the `Girl` class, it causes the `Girl` method `test()` to be called instead of the `Mom` method? It's just so confusing: on one side `Mom` constructor is being called on the other side, the `Girl` method is called, like if `mom` variable has access to both classes.

Comment: Please don't describe your code. Instead [edit] your question to include a [example].

Comment: Agreed - but fundamentally "So mom variable is pointing to a Mom instance right" is wrong, or at least incomplete. You still end up with an instance of Girl. If you call `mom.getClass()` it will return `Girl`. A `Girl` instance is *also* an instance of `Mom` (in terms of inheritance) but the specific concrete class is `Girl`, because that's what you created with the expression `new Girl()`. The type of the variable doesn't change the type of the object.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your help, very helpful, but one more question, if the object is still a Girl object, why is Mom constructor being called ?

Comment: Please don't add follow-up questions in comment threads. I would strongly recommend that you find a good book or web site explaining inheritance thoroughly - otherwise every answer is going to lead to another question that's already explained in documentation/books.

Comment: Oracle has some good onlie tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ (but unfortunately not updated since Java SE 8)

Comment: Please note that with this class hierarchy every instance of Girl is also an instance Mom. I don't know your exact assignment but "every girl is a mom" sounds wrong. Maybe you have your class hierarchy/ association wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reference variable `Mom mom` can reference any instance of `Mom` or instances of subclasses of `Mom`.

In your case the instance is still a `Girl`-instance, which is referenced by a `Mom` reference variable.
You have access to any members of `Mom` (declaration type), but not to the members of `Girl`.
But since the instance is in fact a Girl instance, the implementation of the `Girl` class will be executed.

This mechanism is called "polymorphism".

Comment: thank you for your response but same question as below, if the object is still a Girl object, why is Mom constructor being called ?

Comment: @Idash since a Girl instance "is-a" Mom instance as well, it has to pass the Mom initialization as well.

Comment: Both constructors will be called.

Comment: @DeanJohnson  I got it thank you, one last question please, in that case why "Girl girl = mom" needs to be written "Girl girl = (Girl) mom" since mom is pointing to a Girl instance ?

Comment: For that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java. Basically, the compiler can't guarantee that line is correct and so it needs your help. If you are wrong, you will get an exception in Java.

Comment: @Idash: As I wrote before: "Please don't add follow-up questions in comment threads." That isn't just for *me* - it's *in general on Stack Overflow*. Stack Overflow isn't designed to be a "just one more question" sort of help-desk.